# Unit Testing PHP class with new keyword insight

Tags: php, unit-testing, class, mocking, phpunit

So the other day I have a bad designed PHP class which, for example, populate some objects:

```
class Populator
{
    function populate(array $data): array
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $result[] = new PopulateMeGently($row);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Assume also `PopulateMeGently` is really heavy and the only option is mock it in unit tests.

So how test `populate` method in `Populator` class? Or how to refactor it, to make testable?
I have available IoC and other fancy stuff I can use, but for now everything I tried looks bulky and ugly.

Thank you!

Comment: Is Populator the class you want to test? Are you testing a method that call the populate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the least and cheapest thing you could do would be smth like

```
class Populator
{
    private $rowProcessor;

    public function __construct($rowProcessor){
        $this->rowProcessor = $rowProcessor;
    }

    public function populate(array $data){
        $result = [];
        foreach($data as $row){
            $result[] = $this->rowProcessor->process($row);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

general idea is to have some other object injected into `Populator` and make it responsible for `PopulateMeGently` creation. Don't `new` inside because it's uncontrollable and thus untestable.

Concerning names and implementations it could be some `Factory` that could implement even methods like `makeDefault()`, `makeNullPopulateMeGently()`, `makeFromRaws($data)` or whatever fits to your design and needs.

No you can mock stuff as:

```
class PopulatorTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $populator;
    private $rowProcessorMock;

    public function setUp(){
        $this->rowProcessorMock = $this->getMockBuilder('RowProcessor')
                                       ->setMethods(array('process'))
                                       ->getMock();
        $this->populator = new Populator($this->rowProcessorMock);
    }

    /**
    * @test
    */
    public function canPopulate(){
        $data = array(0, 1);
        $this->rowProcessorMock->expects($this->exactly(2))
                               ->method('process')
                               ->withConsecutive(
                                   [$this->equalTo(0)],
                                   [$this->equalTo(1)]
                                )
                               ->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls('zero', 'one'));
        $result = $this->populator->populate($data);
        $this->assertSame(array('zero', 'one'), $result);
    }
}
```

the `canPopulate` tests all the stuff that needs to happen with `$data` -- all its items get processed in order, result is returned as array of tranformed data. Please note that you don't really need to mock out `PopulateMeGently` (or whatever you'll rename it to). You just make sure that the thing that is responsible for processing your data is called with appropriate parameters and its results are returned appropriately.

Comment: Yes I use factories right now, but wonder if there any other, more elegant way.

Comment: the point is not about using/not using a factory but is rather about pushing dependencies out of the class. In order to make `Populator` testable you have to break `Populator`'s direct dependency on `PopulateMeGently`